# android: cannot resolve symbol 'AdMobAdapterExtras'

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my Admob ads  comply with the Children’s
Online Privacy Protection Act (COPPA).

when I follow instructions given by google developer site [Here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/android-legacy/docs/admob/additional-controls#coppa-setting)

android studio marks my code with red giving me error

```
     cannot resolve symbol 'AdMobAdapterExtras'
```

there is no clear explanation in developers site.

I'm using the same code they provided

```
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

   AdMobAdapterExtras extras = new AdMobAdapterExtras()
        .addExtra("tag_for_child_directed_treatment", 1);

   adRequest.setNetworkExtras(extras);
```

I searched a lot but didn't find anything related.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The site you're linking to seems to be a legacy API documentation. You might want to check the non-legacy one: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting

Comment: What's the difference? Sorry I'm newbie :)

Comment: Legacy means old API docs, which might have changed in the newer releases. If you're having trouble, I recommend you check out the new documentation - the way to do it could be different.

Comment: @zmarkan Thank you. yes I got it.